# How to display username after authentication from database in PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have 2 class files login-form.py and welcome.py

In login-form.py,authentication of user in performed with sqlite3 database.

Code for login-form.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from welcome import Ui_MainWindow
import sqlite3

class Ui_Dialog2(object):
    def login_check(self):
        uname = self.U_name_text.text()
        passw = self.pass_text.text()
        connection = sqlite3.connect("login.db")
        result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?", (uname, passw))
    if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):
        print("Login success")
        self.welcomewindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.welcomewindow)
        Dialog.hide()
        self.welcomewindow.show()
    else:
        print("invalid login")

def setupUi2(self, Dialog):
    Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
    Dialog.resize(301, 386)
    Dialog.setStyleSheet("QDialog{\n"
                         "background-color: rgb(167, 210, 255);\n"
                         "}\n"
                         "QPushButton{\n"
                         "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                         "border:none;\n"
                         "}\n"
                         "QLabel{\n"
                         "color:rgb(255, 23, 54);\n"
                         "font-size:20px;\n"
                         "}")
    self.U_name_Lable = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.U_name_Lable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 111, 21))
    self.U_name_Lable.setObjectName("U_name_Lable")
    self.Pass_Lable = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.Pass_Lable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 150, 111, 21))
    self.Pass_Lable.setObjectName("Pass_Lable")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 201, 31))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(-1)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel#label{\n"
                             "font-size:30px;\n"
                             "}")
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.pass_text = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.pass_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 150, 131, 20))
    self.pass_text.setObjectName("pass_text")
    self.login_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.login_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 190, 61, 23))
    self.login_button.setObjectName("login_button")
    ##############button event################
    self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_check)
    ##########################################
    self.sighup_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
    self.sighup_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 190, 61, 23))
    self.sighup_button.setObjectName("sighup_button")
    self.U_name_text = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
    self.U_name_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 110, 131, 20))
    self.U_name_text.setStyleSheet("")
    self.U_name_text.setObjectName("U_name_text")

    self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
    self.U_name_Lable.setText(_translate("Dialog", "USER NAME"))
    self.Pass_Lable.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PASSWORD"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "LOGIN FORM"))
    self.login_button.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login"))
    self.sighup_button.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Sign-up"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog2()
    ui.setupUi2(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After login i want to display username in QlineEdit in welcome.py file

code for welcome.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 90, 151, 61))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
    font.setPointSize(28)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 551, 61))
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(MainWindow)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 220, 113, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setFamily("Times New Roman")
    font.setPointSize(28)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.label_2.setFont(font)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Good Morning "))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am new to python GUI i dont know how to fetch value from one form to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are implementing the solution is not scalable, it will give you many headaches. Qt Designer recommends not to modify the classes or the files that it generates since for example you want to change the color of a window, add some widgets, you will have to rewrite all the logic and that is time and money wasted.

The classes generated by Qt Designer are not widgets, but are classes used to fill a widget.

What you should do is create another file that takes care of the logic and use the classes generated by Qt Designer.

In this case, you must eliminate the changes to the .py files generated using Qt Designer.

*Recommendation:* use appropriate names for the files, do not use `-`, since these files can be imported by another file and if you do not comply with the rules of python syntax you will have problems. So change the name of `login-form.py` to `login_form.py`.

You must create a new file that will call main.py and in it handle the logic, as it is a QDialog the login will use `exec_()` instead of `show()`, and verify that it is called to `accept()` by the result that returns.

```
import sqlite3

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from login_form import Ui_Dialog2
from welcome import Ui_MainWindow

class LoginDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog2):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_check)

    def login_check(self):
        uname = self.U_name_text.text()
        passw = self.pass_text.text()
        connection = sqlite3.connect("login.db")
        result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?", (uname, passw))
        if result.fetchall():
            self.accept()
        else:
            print("invalid login")

class WelcomeWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = LoginDialog()
    w = WelcomeWindow()
    if login.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        username = login.U_name_text.text()
        w.lineEdit.setText(username)
        w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/a2fd899d5402778d7580caeb0d86fe52).

Comment: Thanks that was some good advice.But still, my logic is not clear.can you please share some other examples.

Comment: @user3135049 
Your implementation is not correct, and I can not base your progress since the answer would be of poor quality and would not serve future readers, so you understand all the changes I have added a link where you will see the complete and workable code.

Comment: @user3135049 
What examples do you want?

Comment: a well structured small application will help me understand the working.if you have done any.for educational purpose only.

Comment: @user3135049 review the following: https://github.com/CodeHuntersLab/CuriElements

Comment: Thanks for the example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622587/eyllanesc hi can u please help me with my code?

Comment: @user3135049 
First mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: sure i will mark as correct but this is not the problem.i have posted another questoin please respond on that problem.

Comment: Then do it, when you do I'll try to help you.